# Visual Studio 2008 + MOSS 2007 : Updating ASP.NET 3.5 Web Application to SharePoint

Tags: 2007, visual-studio, asp.net

What are the steps to updating ASP.NET 3.5 Web application (compiled using Visual Studio 2008) to SharePoint Server 2007?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just "move" an ASP.NET application to SharePoint. The security model is different, the navigation model is different, the deployment model is different, etc.

You basically have three choices:

- Have links in to the ASP.NET application in SharePoint and vice versa. This only requires minor changes.
- Use an IFrame to expose the ASP.NET application inside SharePoint pages. This option is most definitely a kludge but it can be done
- Rebuild your ASP.NET application as a true SharePoint application. You won't be starting from scratch (you'll be able to salvage some code and markup) but you will be building a new application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite understand the question.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Host the web application in sharepoint?  If so, i would host the web application elsewhere and use the page viewer webpart to display the site in sharepoint.

UPDATE:

Oh yea, now I realize you are the same person that asked the other question I answered ( [MOSS 2007 + Visual Studio 2008 : How to I deploy a Visual Studio 2008 Web Application to SharePoint Server 2007](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19839/moss-2007-visual-studio-2008-how-to-i-deploy-a-visual-studio-2008-web-applica) ).  Which one of my questions met the need for it to be an application page (_layouts)?

Comment: Hi Steve, this question is a new question not related to my another question posted. However, according to the link that you provided in my another question, I notice that if a developer modify his/her web application in visual studio, he/she will need to re-compile and update SharePoint. So, I was wondering how to update sharepoint if a re-compilation of the codes for asp.net web application is needed. (Anyway, it will still be needed because developer usually need to upgrade their codes to fit in new user requirements). In my previous question that you point out - it was more on deployment.